# Mathematica 9 how to import in a effecient way images for batch processing

Tags: image, performance, import, wolfram-mathematica, batch-processing

For the post process of a big batch of bmp images I'm currently using this script in mathematica 9 to import the batch:

```
Dir = "C:\\...";
SetDirectory[Dir];
Impimg = Import[#] & /@ FileNames["*.bmp"];
```

It does work but I can see two problems :

1) First it'is very slow !

2)Second all images are stored in a list. This consuming a hell of memory and it'is actually not required by the process I'm using as the process only need the image itself.

Any idea to overcome this two problems ?

Daniel

Comment: So just import one image at a time ?  Or have I missed the point of your question ?

Comment: I have more than 100 pics to process so working with the batch is important to me.

Answer (score 1):

To cut the memory usage to half, in this case you can set the [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24HistoryLength.html?q=%24HistoryLength&lang=en) to `0` which forces Mathematica to not keep copies of the data in the [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Out.html?q=Out&lang=en) list.

For increasing the Import speed, you can save all the images in a multipage tiff file and then import them at once which is a lot faster.

`$HistoryLength = 0`

You may also use the [`ParallelMap[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelMap.html?q=ParallelMap&lang=en) function which uses multiple cores (depending on your license) and is usually faster :

`Impimg = ParallelMap[Import[#] &, FileNames["*.bmp"]];`